# How do you get the the string between two markers even if there is multiple for the string inside it in nodes

Tags: node.js, string, substring

I was trying to make a node's program that takes a string, and gets all of the content inside it:

```js
var str = "Hello {world}!";

console.log(getBracketSubstrings(str)); // => ['world']
```

It works, but when I do:

```
var str = "Hello {world{!}}";
console.log(getBracketSubstrings(str)); // => ['world{!']
```

It returns `['world{!}']`, when I want it to return:

```
['world{!}']
```

Is there anyway to do this to a string in nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pattern with a capture group, matching from `{` followed by any char except a closing curly using `[^}]*` until you encounter a `}`

```
{([^}]*)}
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y1dftC/1)

```js
const getBracketSubstrings = s => Array.from(s.matchAll(/{([^}]*)}/g), x => x[1]);
console.log(getBracketSubstrings("Hello {world}!"));
console.log(getBracketSubstrings("Hello {world{!}}"));
```

Comment: This is good, but is there a way to get the final }?

Comment: @user14929391 Like this? `{([^{}]+(?:{[^{}]*})?)}` https://regex101.com/r/GZJaWH/1

Comment: That works great, and sorry to bother you again, but it doesn’t seem to work if there is more than one bracket substring in another bracket substring, is that possible? If not, that’s fine

Comment: Then you have to match [balanced parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses?answertab=votes#tab-top) Javascript regex does not support recursion.